# Does TypeScript have type definitions for InputEvent?

Tags: typescript

Is there any node `@types/*` module or anything that can provide type definition for `InputEvent`?

[Read here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) on `InputEvent`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is there any node @types/* module or anything that can provide type definition for InputEvent?

- You can install it from `@types/dom-inputevent`.
- It is not in the default `dom.d.ts` right now cause its not widely supported / finalized as mentioned here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent

Comment: Would like to see some citation around "not widely supported"

Comment: @BradJohnson "not widely supported / finalized", meaning it's experimental, which is cited.

Answer (score 19):

> Is there any node @types/* module or anything that can provide type definition for InputEvent?

Yes, there is [@types/dom-inputevent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dom-inputevent) which you can use for this.

Answer (score 11):

`InputEvent` is poorly defined in `@types/dom-inputevent`. As noted by others, this is because it's experimental at the time of this posting.

Instead, consider using `KeyboardEvent`:

```
inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', (e: KeyboardEvent) => 
    const input = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
    console.log(input, e.key)
)
```

Comment: 2020 and this is still the solution for me