# How to get typescript method callback working in VueJs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typescript-typings

I am developing with vuejs using typescript and facing issues with method callback working. I am basically trying to update my data by wrapping it in a debounce function. I am using debounce function from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-debounce module. Here is the code example:

```
import { debounce } from 'ts-debounce';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    data() {
        return {
            input: '# hello',
        };
    },

    methods: {
        updateWithDebounce: debounce(function(e: any) {
            this.input = e.target.value;
        }, 2000),

       update(e: any) {
            this.input = e.target.value;
        },
    }
```

This code functionally works, but fails with compilation error:

'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    40 |
    41 |             updateWithDebounce: debounce(function(e: any) {

> 42 |                 this.input = e.target.value;
>          |                 ^
>       43 |             }, 2000),
>   Would greatly appreciate if someone can help me resolve this error.

Comment: Use Class-Style Vue Components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components  This will let TS see what `this` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply not possible. The type information is getting lost between with the closure created by debounce function. With Vue, `this` context is calculated as a combined instance. Currently, there is no way to correctly pass it to debounce function.

In this scenario, you have two choices:

```
methods: {
    // set this pointer to explicitly any. But you will lose typing info.
    updateWithDebounce: debounce(function(this: any, e: any) {
        this.input = e.target.value;
    }, 2000),
}
```

Secondly, you can use arrow function and that will preserve typing information:

```
methods: {
    // set this pointer to explicitly any. This will mask your typing info though.
    updateWithDebounce() {
        // call debounced function immediately.
        debounce(() => this.input = e.target.value, 2000)();
    },
}
```

However, this is clearly inefficient.

Also, I don't recommend that you use debouncing this way. Imagine you have debounced function with a delay of `2000ms`. If your `Vue` component is destroyed during this period, then it will surely cause trouble. I don't think `ts-debounce` has knowledge of when Vue component is destroyed.

The correct way is to use something like `Rxjs` streams or `Observables` for debouncing. Or build your own helper function.

Finally, you can use class syntax `vue-class-component` and build your own decorator like this:

```
@Component({})
export default class SimpleComponent extends Vue {

    // Selected value of each menu item
    public someValue = 1;

    public data() {

        return {
            // Some data...
        };
    }

    @Debounce(2000)
    public updateWithDebounce() {

    }
}
```

It is not very difficult to build your own debouncer: https://github.com/bvaughn/debounce-decorator

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to get it working based on your suggestion. Another related question. In above example, I defined parameter 'e' as type 'any', although I know from console.log, it is of type InputEvent. But don't know how to import InputEvent type.  How do I find and import appropriate type class?

Comment: @Raja, I had the same question. Here is the thread that will answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714315/does-typescript-have-type-definitions-for-inputevent

Comment: Is there really no way to type `this` in this case `updateWithDebounce: debounce(function(this: any, e: any)`?