# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'InputEvent'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

As described in [Does TypeScript have type definitions for InputEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714315/does-typescript-have-type-definitions-for-inputevent), I tried to use [`@types/dom-inputevent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dom-inputevent) to obtain `InputEvent` in my Angular 7 project. But it shows `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'InputEvent'` whenever I use it.

Is there any need to "register" it in the Angular project or is it a bug?

If a fix is not available, I just want a convenient way to achieve the same result as `event.data` in `InputEvent`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to use @types/dom-inputevent in unit tests for an Angular 6 app. In my case, the cause was that I had an explicit 'types' entry in my tsconfig.spec.js, as outlined below.

**tsconfig.json** (irrelevant parts omitted)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "typeRoots": [
       "node_modules/@types"
     ]
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.spec.js** (irrelevant parts omitted)

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "types": [
    "jasmine",
    "node"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there's a `types` entry that lists explicit types that should be made available during compilation. This overrides the `typeRoots` setting in the parent tsconfig.json, so only @types/jasmine and @types/node were available when compiling my unit tests. See also here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types.

**Solution** is to add `dom-inputevent` to the `types` list e.g.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "types": [
    "jasmine",
    "node",
    "dom-inputevent"
  ]
}
```

Another approach would have been to remove the types entry altogether. If I did that, `typeRoots` would have kicked in and looked for all types under node_modules/@types, thus including `@types/dom-inputevent` too.

Comment: Years passed and I finally got an answer lol. I think the answer makes sense so I accept it, but I'm not currently working on that project and I'm too busy to verify it. It just comes to my mind that Firefox doesn't natively support `event.data` in `InputEvent`. Does that package provide the deserved behaviors for Firefox?

Comment: My case is different than yours and I just can't get it working... =/