# Event target doesn't exist on the lib dom interface in typescript defintion

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, events

I'm building out a simple color picker for a front end using typescript. I'm adding an event listener to the color picker input:

The html:

```
<input id="color-picker" type="color" value="" />
```

The typescript:

```
private grabUiElements() {
  this.colorPicker = document.querySelector("#color-picker")
}

private addListners() {
  this.colorPicker?.addEventListener("change", this.updateBrickColor.bind(this))
}

 private updateBrickColor(changeEvent: Event) {
    let hexColor = changeEvent?.target?.value // ! here's where the problem is

    const red = hexColor & 0xFF
    color >>= 8
    const green = hexColor & 0xFF
    color >>= 8
    const blue = hexColor & 0xFF

    doOtherStuff(red,green,blue)
  }
```

The problem I'm running into is that the typescript compiler is telling me that the event target doesn't have a value property, but it definitely does have it:

[image: value def exists]

I double checked the input change event docs on MDN and they definitely have an example of just this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#text_input_element

[image: docs]

And I'm definitely using the dom Event interface:

[image: dom event interface]

So I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. I know I can use an `any` for the parameter type, but I'd prefer to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hey, there are probably things that don't have a value in `change` events so since it's not guaranteed it's probably without `Event`. You can do  `(e.target as HTMLInputElement).value` which _should_ work.

Comment: This is also a good place to contribute to TypeScript's type definitions too.

Comment: You need to cast your `event.target as HTMLInputElement` or equivalent, as typescript can't figure out the exact type of an element by itself based on the generic `Event`. Since standard 'Element' does not have these props, the element inside the event just has the most general, non-specific shared description of the target.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714315/does-typescript-have-type-definitions-for-inputevent

Answer (score 0):

change it to `changeEvent: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks for the quick replies in the comments.

I'm not sure how I was supposed to implement the other provided answer:

> change it to changeEvent: ChangeEvent

but casting suggested in the comments to the question worked fine:

```
 private updateBrickColor(changeEvent: Event) {
    const target = changeEvent.target as HTMLInputElement
    
    // ? chop off that `#` from the string and parse the rest
    let hexColor = parseInt(target.value.slice(1, target.value.length), 16) 

    const blue = hexColor & 0xFF
    hexColor >>= 8
    const green = hexColor & 0xFF
    hexColor >>= 8
    const red = hexColor & 0xFF
  }
```

[image: solved]

I'm good to go, thanks again!